# How to create DLLAPI() template mixin in the D programming language that behaves similar to the well-known DLLAPI (or similar) macro in C/C++?

Tags: templates, d, mixins

As most of you know, in C/C++ I would write a macro similar to this one when I deal with dynamic libraries.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#  define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#  define DLLAPI
#endif
```

What I would like to do is a template mixin in the D programming language so I can nicely declare functions from a certain library:

```
mixin DLLAPI(int, "function1", string, int); // int function1(const char* arg1, int arg2)
mixin DLLAPI(byte, "function2");             // char function2()
// etc
```

First question is - is it a good idea to use template mixin for this, or just write the code inside `version (Windows) {} version (linux) {} //...` blocks?
Second question - how to nicely take all the types after the function name? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simply to use extern(System) instead of extern(C)/extern(Windows) - it defaults to stdcall in Windows and cdecl in Linux and whanot.

Thus:

```
extern(System) {
    int function(...) foo;
}
```

Comment: +1 - thanks! I have no idea how I missed the part about extern(System) in the documentation. :)